# Memory issue while video saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks

I'm picking video from camera and save to local directory using bellow code

```
NSURL *selectedVideoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:selectedVideoURL];

NSString *filePath = [UICommonMethods getSaveVideoPath];
[videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

but the problem is when I record 5 to 10 mnts video the app crash due to memory leak. Anybody knows how can we control memory
but keep in mind I picking video from camera not from library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the image picker to create a video, it creates a temporary video file. You can move this file to where you need it, instead of loading it into memory (which is bad anyway) and then copying it:

```
// Get paths
NSURL *selectedVideoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSString *filePath = [UICommonMethods getSaveVideoPath];
NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

// Move file
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:selectedVideoURL toURL:fileUrl error:nil];
```

If you need access to the data of the file, use a [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read it a bit at a time, instead of all at once...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:selectedVideoURL];
```

Above class methods, the videoData can not release directly, try follow:

```
NSData *videoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: selectedVideoURL];
```

// do something.

```
[videoData release];
videoData = nil;
```